# When you have a script where you import a large amount of data at the beginning, how can you avoid repeating this import when you edit and re-run?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm relatively new to Python and learning how to use it in a data science context. The assignments I'm working on involve importing lots of data and then plotting, performing some calculations, etc. Each time I edit something minor (i.e., change a scale on a plot), I need to rerun the script, which takes a lot of time since importing the data is slow. I'm using Pycharm Pro.

Is there a way to re-run only portions of the script, and avoid re-running the data import?

Comment: I would suggest either using a smaller data source for testing that takes less time to import, or trying to write larger blocks of code at once before testing, rather than testing after writing only a few lines.

Comment: To re-iterate @BobSmith, testing with small data-sets is exceptionally useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one file that imports your data and another that generates your plots. When you make some small change to the plotter simply import it again and you can pass your data to your plotting function. Forgoing the terminal you could set up a loop that waist for some user input (just so that you can control it) and re-loads your plotter and regenerates your plots.

```
import data
d = data.loadData()
while True:
    input("Press enter to (re-)plot data.")
    import plotter
    plotter.plot(d)
```